# Reading a stack trace

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm trying to track down the cause of an exception, sometimes the last line in the stack trace is where it occurs.  Other times it isn't and you need to set breakpoints on other lines mentioned in the stacktrace.

As an example, if an exception occurs on the 2nd to last line (2nd from top), why does the stack trace not stop at this line? It instead prints one additional line, which is deceiving.  At run time, the exception is displayed in this file mentioned as the last line in the stack trace.  But if you set a breakpoint on the 2nd to last line mentioned in the stack trace, it is then clear what the problem is.

Comment: Please post (abbreviated) stack trace examples and point out where precisely you find the information misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 cases where you might see a slightly different stack trace then where your debugger goes to when an exception occurs:

1. An assembly built in release mode can end up being optimized and the code you are debugging might not exactly represent the IL that is running.
2. If you have a try{do();}catch(Exception e) { throw e; } it will change your stack trace.
3. If you have "just my code" enabled and the exception is thrown from external code which you have the source code for, you might get a stack trace slightly different from where the debugger wants to stop.